# What is the correct format for a JSON-Array used by angucomplete-alt?

Tags: php, json, angularjs

I try to use remote data with angucomplete-alt (https://github.com/darylrowland/angucomplete):

```
<angucomplete-alt id="searchfield"
      pause="100"
      remote-url="search.php?searchstr="
      remote-url-data-field="results"
      title-field="title"
      description-field="description"
      minlength="1"
      input-class="form-control form-control-small"/>
```

My PHP-file looks like this:

```
$ds = array('title' => 'title', 'description' => 'some text');
$response = array ("results" => $ds);
print_r(json_encode($response));
exit;
```

So there should always be one single result within searching anything. But there is just the message 'No results found'. What am I doing wrong with the JSON-Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angucomplete-alt needs a top-level array. So you have to use:

```
$response = array ("results" => array($ds));
echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why did you use print_r() ?

> print_r — Prints human-readable information about a variable

That's probably not what you want.

```
echo json_encode($response);
```